# How can I assign a partial to a class function parameter, with the partial type coming from a field?

Tags: typescript

I have classes that has a `state` field and a `setState` function, similar to React:

```
abstract class ClassWithPartial {

    onStart() {}

    state = {}
    setState(newState: Partial<this["state"]>) {
        this.state = {...this.state, ...newState}
    }

}

class ClassThatExtends extends ClassWithPartial {
    override state = {
        existing: true as boolean,
        loading: true as boolean,
    }
    override onStart() {
        this.setState({loading: false, existing: true}) // doesn't throw an error
        this.setState({loading: false}) // throws an error: Argument of type '{ loading: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<this["state"]>'.
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4&ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwq9B1AlhABYAKwUE%20wyCA3gFD0LMID2AdgMoTkQAUASjoBfRiwSRgEAKYIAvCKYsw0iNynS%207aQHd1MgFwIyFKsgA8xfGADaAIkky7AXQB8QhuPFWwAOkeyCrS%20IT7%20PDIANAghvtp6EdKi4qL0qShoGNiZACpEUgCiAB4y7AAmGNIl0uVZOGAExCaU1HRKzKwAbtJQUPhlsgHybV4sVdaU7ADmRtAArrJoCCCsrMjSwOyR7V7IrMBl%20NOzUAsISytrG1s7ySxdPX0DbFw8FIIjowhhKmqJfLQ9gcjjMEAAzagqaLjSAgk4LYRCAD0SIQZVY0jA7AA5IhiFBWDpzuwEI9WFAdt4iNZ-Kp9JpAftDsdwZCksjUfjCRhNqTeuSjABBKBTOYAWxqiFYYO%20AE8AA6ybG0BBA5mgiHIFQAbgQwmxCGsCHYrEQmXwU3YoHW31YCHl5GAEpkUDYMogCqVzTMlmptgciRcrmxvluaSAA)

I have been trying to type the `setState` function's parameter, but when you use the function with only a partial of the state it throws a typescript error:

```
Argument of type '{ loading: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<this["state"]>'.ts(2345)
```

This shouldn't happen, as it should accept a partial of it. It works outside of a class, but I need it in a class:

```
let state = {
    existing: true as boolean,
    loading: true as boolean,
}

function setState(newState: Partial<typeof state>) {
    state = {...state, ...newState}
}

setState({loading: false}) // no errors!
```

To clarify: this isn't a question about React.

I’m using typescript v4.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this["state"]` isn't a type.

Try creating a type for the `state` member, like this:

```
type State = {
  existing: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
};


abstract class ClassWithPartial {

    onStart() {}

    state: Partial<State> = {};

    setState(newState: Partial<State>) {
        this.state = {...this.state, ...newState}
    }

}

class ClassThatExtends extends ClassWithPartial {
    override state = {
        existing: true as boolean,
        loading: true as boolean,
    }
    override onStart() {
        this.setState({loading: false, existing: true});
        this.setState({loading: false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to explicitly type [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) context:

```js
abstract class ClassWithPartial {
    onStart() { }

    state = {
        existing: false,
        loading: false
    }

    setState(newState: Partial<this['state']>) {

        this.state = { ...this.state, ...newState }
    }

}

class ClassThatExtends extends ClassWithPartial {

    override state = {
        existing: true,
        loading: true,
    }

    override onStart(this: ClassThatExtends) { // this is explicitly typed
        this.setState({ loading: false, existing: true })
        this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `this` to `Foobar` should solve the problem.

```js
class Foobar {
  state = {
    existing: true as boolean,
    loading: true as boolean,
  }
  setState(newState: Partial<Foobar["state"]>) {
    this.state = { ...this.state, ...newState }
  }
  onStart() {
    this.setState({ loading: false, existing: true })
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }
}
```

You may have hit an edge case of TypeScript. In my understanding, the first `setState` call should not be able to compile either since `this["state"]` can be set to arbitrary subtype of `{ existing: boolean, loading: boolean }` by subclasses of `Foobar` and it cannot guarantee `{ loading: false, existing: true }` nor `{ loading: false }` is compatible to the type defined by the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting with a default parameter works:

```
abstract class ClassWithPartial {

    onStart() {}

    state = {}
    setState<T = Partial<this["state"]>>(newState: T) { // type cast here
        this.state = {...this.state, ...newState}
    }

}


class ClassThatExtends extends ClassWithPartial {
    override state = {
        existing: true as boolean,
        loading: true as boolean,
    }
    override onStart() {
        this.setState({loading: false, existing: true}) // no error
        this.setState({loading: false, }) // also no error!
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwq9B1AlhABYAKwUE+wyCA3gFD0LMID2AdgMoTkQAUASjoBfRiwSRgEAKYIAvCKYsw0iNynSAPABV5CMhSrJNxfGADaAIkkzLAXQB8Dvu2kB3dTIBcCbUNoIAPSBCBAAngAOsrBoiETSUNJK4symYAB0NrIKtOl5aZk8MgA0CHnprh5F0qLiovT19ChoGNgt2kRSAKIAHjLsACYY0n3Sg604YATEBpTUdMlsAG4JUPgDsll6DCksI2aU7ADmPtAArrJoCCCsrMjSwOzFi+LIrMAD+MenUBcIVzc7g8notaixWCsoGsNmwuDwKIIFrtUkQzJlVJ5pHxaG8Pl8TggAGbUFSlfaQfE-C7CITBBDsVgIVasKAvFgFFRqarY3Gfb5EknSUo0oIhEmMhlMqEsgCEoIaQA)

Also in the playground, if you hit ctrl + space after the extra comma you can see that it does autocomplete, which is great. I think this works because its not the right type according to Typescript, so it just changes the type parameter. But for whatever reason it still treats it as the partial.

The downside is that it doesn’t throw an error if the type is wrong.